# I am unable to make a ssms sql query work in databricks

Tags: postgresql, databricks

I have a query that works fine in SSMS yet when I try the same in databricks it fails because of a nvarchar(2048) component. here is the segment of sql that works in ssms but not databricks.

```
    cast(concat(c.client_id, '::' + kr.name) as nvarchar(2048)) as role_hierarchy,
    cast('' as varchar(36)) as child_role_id,
    cast('' as varchar(36)) as child_role_realm,
    cast('' as varchar(255)) as child_client_role_client_id,
    cast('' as nvarchar(255)) as child_role_name,
```

here is the error I receive...

Error in SQL statement: ParseException:
DataType nvarchar(2048) is not supported.(line 8, pos 48)

how can I accomplish this concept in postgresql?

Comment: There is absolutely no need for all those cast in Postgres to begin with. But the equivalent would be `varchar(2048)`

Comment: Hey Did you find an answer to this? Currently dealing with the same issue. I need a Pyspark equivalent to NVARCHAR).